# USB Audio streaming Windows to Windows

Tags: windows, audio, streaming, usb

Here is what I am trying to do:

D1 Laptop (Win 10) -> D2 Desktop (Win 7) -> Headphones

The last part is easy, my issue is only the audio transmission from Device1 to Device2. This means that I need a program that can run on both machines and talk to the other instance of itself, suggesting to one machine that it is an output device (speakers) and to the other that it is an input device (microphone).

There are drivers that encode and stream audio via USB (obviously), but those always require custom hardware of some sort, so I only ever get one half of the puzzle.

Does anyone know of some sort of software (virtual audio mixer, USB headphones and USB microphone drivers using the same encoding (and some way to have them talk to each other), anything really)?

Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

You can easily transfer audio/mic on your LAN using [VBAN](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/vban.htm) protocol. Since you are on Windows machine just install [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) edition which have got VBAN implemented. Android and iOS are also supported.

[image: vban in voicemeeter]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AnyDesk](https://www.anydesk.com), it's a remote-desktop solution, has free offering and transmits the sound.